# Send ASCII Data to UART3 on Android Things with 3 Byes of 0xFF at the end

Tags: java, android, android-things, nextion

I am trying to interface a Nextion HMI Serial Screen to Android Things, specifically the PICO-PI-IMX6UL

I am using the sample-uartloopback template as a starting place.

What I need to do is send the following payload over serial (UART3) in a certain format and in ASCII

page 1

1. The instruction is ended with three bytes "0xff 0xff 0xff"
2. All the instructions and parameters are in ASCII
3. All the instructions are in lowercase letters

   mLoopbackDevice.write(buffer, buffer.length);

Where buffer is the payload with the three terminating bytes.

The thing is the screen wants in in ASCII but I can only send in the bytearray...

I have tried multiple ways and I cant seem to get it to work.

What would be the proper way to format a string of "page 1" and then add the terminating bytes?

I have it working in a node app but java is blowing my mind right now...

I have tried:

```
String strCommand = "page 1";
byte b = (byte)0xFF;
byte[] endCommand = {b,b,b};
byte[] cmd = strCommand.getBytes();
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
outputStream.write(cmd);
outputStream.write(endCommand);
byte[] payload = outputStream.toByteArray();
Screen.write(payload, payload.length);
```

but that does not work.

I can read data (nothing useful at the moment) so I can confirm the communication is fine and It works in my Node app, but I need to port it to Android Things...

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: This returns the correct format for me in JS

```
function hex(str) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0, l = str.length; i < l; i ++) {
            var ascii = str.charCodeAt(i);
            arr.push(ascii);
    }
    arr.push(255);
    arr.push(255);
    arr.push(255);
    return new Buffer(arr);
}
```

Comment: ooi what does the equivalent node js code look like?

Comment: Added the working JS version. I pass "Page 1" to the hex function

Comment: tbh I can't see a problem. The error might lie elsewhere, does `Screen.write` manipulate the byte array?

Comment: Connect Tx and Rx lines of PICO-PI-IMX6UL UART3 to each other and check what you really send.

Comment: Good idea. Let me do that and see what I get... I don't know why that did not cross my mind..

Comment: @Dreambeats any update? I'm interested